# Inserting a LinkedList into another LinkedList

Tags: java

At the moment, I have a method in my LinkedList (not the Java's one) class that adds single nodes to a LinkedList and it looks like this:

```
  public void add(int index, T v) {
     if(isValidIntervalPosition(index)) {
        Node<T> n = new Node<T>(v);
        if(index == 0) {
           n.setNext(head);
           head = n;
        }
        else {
           Node<T> m = head;
           int count = 1;
           while(count < index) {
              m = m.getNext();
              count++;
           }

           n.setNext(m.getNext());
           m.setNext(n);
        } 

        sz++;
     }
  }
```

But I would like to implement another method that adds the nodes from an input LinkedList to the current LinkedList.

Here is the skeleton:

```
 public void add(int position, LinkedList<T> list) {


 }
```

I've been playing with it for a few hours with no result. How would I go about doing this if I already can insert single nodes?

Comment: Simply call your own method to insert the 1st element at the desired position, the 2nd element at the next position and so on...

Comment: I'm having trouble with the loop I need to actually call the first method

Comment: show us what you have troubles with. You completely left  that part out....

Comment: well say for example if I do: for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
          add(position++, list);
          
      }

Comment: I get a stack overflow error... I'm not sure I'm iterating over the elements properly

Comment: does your list have a `get()` method?

Comment: @DanielRojas Because you are calling `add(int, LinkedList<T>)`, not `add(int, T)`. It's endless recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply do

```
public void add(int position, final LinkedList<T> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        add(position++, list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require OPs `LinkedList` class to implement `Iterable`, we don't know if it does... (I suspect not)

Comment: I'm afraid jlordo is right and I don't have Iterable implemented, so I get an error :(

Comment: Yeah right, just use a classic `for` then. I edited my answer.

Comment: @m0skit0: now `t` is not declared.

Comment: I'm getting a stack overflow error with this. Would it have something to do with not incrementing size? (sz in my code);

Comment: The stackoverflow error is most likely due to your LinkedList implementation. You can try asking another question since it has nothing to do with your current question :) We'll be glad to check it out.

Comment: @jlordo Yeah right, fixed it. I'm not even compiling this so sorry for the stupid errors :P

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public void add(int position, LinkedList<T> list) {
    int index = position;
    for(T elem : list) {
        add(index ++, elem) // call to your implementation + increment index
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require OPs `LinkedList` class to implement `Iterable`, we don't know if it does... (I suspect not)

Comment: That's true. He may have to use any other way to iterate over the element of the list if not. This ``for each`` loop is just an example.

Comment: Any suggestions on a way to iterate without the for-each loop?

Comment: You can either implement ``Iterable`` so that the for each loop will work. It is probably a convenient way of doing so your class can be easily used. Otherwise you can simply go through your elements getting the root node and calling ``getNext()`` as we see in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is NOT to touch every single node of the list to add.
Instead, to insert `list` between nodes `u` and `v` you make `u.next` point at `list.head` and `list.tail.next` (the last element, I don't know if you store `list.tail` it or have to iterate through all nodes of `list` to get it) point at `v` (the old `u.next`)

It is hard to write a code example without knowing the details of your list class (i.e. which members and methods there are).

Especially, since implementing your own LinkedList is seldomly useful for your program but usually an exercise for data structures, this is the most important thing to get about the "add a whole list" exercise.

Answer (score -1):

Here first get the size of existing list and then add to the current position

```
 public static void add(int position, LinkedList<String> list) {
      System.err.println(list.size());
      list.add(list.size(), "aaa");
      System.out.println(list.get(1));

     }
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This is not Java's `LinkedList`.